# Ruby on rails 3. return modal form errors in modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, error-handling, modal-dialog

Evening .  im using a jquery tools modal that loads my form.  the form loads fine and submits.  my problem is correctly displaying form errors in the same modal.

I'm also using dynamic_form to show errors.

Currently the code is fairly simple. as you can see in the controller in rendering the partial when an error is present.  this is where the problem is. i need to get that partual to return inside the modal.  i've read a bunch of documents and solutions (including some on this site) but none are functioning correctly.

Any idea how i can make this work?

href code

```
link_to new_registrant_path(:var => var.id), :rel => "#overlay"
```

JS to load modal

```
 $(function() {
     $("a[rel]").overlay({
         mask: 'darkred',
         effect: 'apple',
         speed: 'fast',
         onBeforeLoad: function() {
             var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
             wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
         }
    });
});
```

create action in controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @registrant.save
    format.html //some code
  else
    format.html { render :partial => "new" }
  end
end
```

thanks in advance